# Clarification on Bonita BPMN

Tags: bpmn, business-process, bonita

Where does Bonita store its information? For example in Activiti bpmn, we have default system tables. Do we have something similar in Bonita?
Also, is there a plugin in Eclipse for configuring Bonita BPMN? I tried creating a diagram using Bonita Studio. I found that Bonita has a separate Tomcat bundle. But I want it trigger it from my eclipse server. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Bonita BPM use a H2 database to store the system data.
You can find more information here :
http://documentation.bonitasoft.com/database-configuration-1#h2default

If you want to use Bonita BPM in your eclipse, you can use the Engine API :
http://documentation.bonitasoft.com/getting-started-bonita-bpm-engine-apis

Comment: I would add that Bonita BPM Studio is for design and development. Tomcat bundle is for pre-prod, and production.